# Dúvida sobre funções em Haskell

Tags: haskell

Resolvi mergulhar no mundo da programação funcional recentemente, e fui apresentado a linguagem Haskell. Comecei a pesquisar sobre como a linguagem funciona, e logo consegui pegar os principais conceitos. Então, comecei a trabalhar com listas, e decidi reimplementar algumas funções já existentes, apenas para fins de prática.

Com isso, decidi fazer minha versão da função `reverse`, que chamei de `revert`.

O conceito dela é simples. Recebe uma lista, e retorna ela invertida. Sua implementação é a seguinte:

```
revert :: [a] -> [a]
revert [] = []
revert a = revert (tail a) ++ [head a]
```

Ela funcionou, como é possível ver na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, decidi fazer um outro teste, recebendo o resultado da função na mesma variável que eu passei por parâmetro, conforme imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele executa a função normalmente, porém quando consulto o valor da variável `x`, ele parece entrar em algum tipo de loop, e é necessário apertar `Ctrl+C` pra cancelar.

Detalhe, ela acontece apenas se eu receber na mesma variável que eu passei por parâmetro. Se eu tivesse feito:

```
let y = revert x
```

teria funcionado, eu testei.

Porque isso acontece? É alguma peculiaridade que eu não peguei relacionado a algum conceito de programação funcional? Pesquisei mas não achei nada. Talvez eu não tenha encontrado os termos corretos para usar na pesquisa...

Comment: Me fez lembrar da materia de LP, o sofrimento rs +1 boa pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após leitura (e uma pergunta no SO em inglês), eu consegui entender o motivo disso acontecer, e vou deixar a explicação aqui para contribuir com quem possa interessar.

Tudo isso aconteceu porque Haskell usa o conceito de "[avaliação preguiçosa](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_evaluation)". Isso significa que nenhuma expressão é avaliada quando associada a uma variável, e sim **adiada** até que seu resultado seja necessário para outras operações.

Mesmo tendo isso em mente, o código

```
let x = [0..10]
x = revert x
```

mesmo assim parece perfeitamente normal. Porém, o que aconteceu para que ele não conseguisse me mostrar o resultado de `x` foi o seguinte:

na linha `x = revert x` , a expressão `revert x`foi associada a variável `x`, mas como expressão, e não como resultado. Ou seja, essa expressão não foi **avaliada**.

Então, quando consultei o valor de `x` o Haskell **avaliou** o valor da operação `revert x`, substituindo à direita, de modo que ficou:

`revert (revert x)`

e novamente:

`revert (revert (revert ... x)..)`

E assim, infinitamente :)